# Delete files from a folder with changing content

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, file, delete-file

I have a main thread and a thread that process some files. When there are changes in a folder monitored by the main thread, a signal is sent to the processing thread to start. After processing a file, I would like it removed and then let the folder check whether there are any more files in the folder. If there are then repeat the process.

My problem is in the repeated check of the folder. on the processing thread. The function is listed in the code below where the problem is that i cannot delete the files from the folder. I'm pretty stuck, so any inputs is appreciated.

**In dataprocessor.h**

```
...
QList<QString> justProcessed;
...
```

**In dataprocessor.cpp**

```
void DataProcessor::onSignal() {
// Will keep running as long as there are files in the spool folder, eating it's way through
bool stillFiles = true;

QDir dir(this->monitoredPath);
dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
dir.setSorting(QDir::Time);

while(stillFiles) {

    // Have to update on each iteration, since the folder changes.
    dir.refresh();

    QFileInfoList fileList = dir.entryInfoList();
    QString activeFile = "";

    foreach(QFileInfo file, fileList) {

        if((file.suffix() == "txt") && !justProcessed.contains(file.fileName())) {
            // Is a text file. Set for processing and break foreach loop
            activeFile = file.fileName();
            break;
        }

    }

    // If none of the files passed the requirements, then there are no more spl files in the folder.
    qDebug() << activeFile;
    if(activeFile == "") {
        qDebug() << "Finished";
        emit finished();
        stillFiles = false;
    }

    // File is a new file, start processing
    qDebug() << "Selected for processing";
    qDebug() << monitoredPath + "/" + activeFile;
    if(!dir.remove(monitoredPath + "/" + activeFile)) qDebug() << "Could not remove file";

    justProcessed.append(activeFile);

} // While end
}
```

Please let me know if I missed to provide some information.

Comment: Is your Print Spooler service running?

Comment: "i cannot delete the files from the folder" - what does that mean? Does the remove() return false? Then use `activeFile = file.absoluteFilePath();` to get the complete path, that's easier to handle. Then, to remove it: `QFile f(activeFile); if (!f.remove()) qDebug("Could not remove %s: %s", qPrintable(activeFile), qPrintable(f.errorString()));` to learn why it failed.

Comment: @KubaOber The reason i initialized the QString was because i have had other problems with initialization in the thread. If i for example define an int and i don't initialize it with e.g. a 0, then i get what looks to be a memory address, even though i did not initialize it as a pointer. I learned how to use threads the other day, so some things i'm not quite sure of yet. Nice point with `isEmpty()`. Thank you.

Comment: @Nejat Yes it is. I double checked it, thank you.

Comment: Yes i know Kuba, it was just an unnecessary precaution because everything kept failing, so i tried whatever small things i could find :) @FrankOsterfeld Sorry for not being clear on that. Yes, remove returns false. When outputting the error, as you described, it tells me that the file is being used by another process.

Comment: If the Print Spooler is running i think it gets the files opened and prevents them from deleting.

Comment: I just tried removing the while loop and going all the way back to just printing out the contents of the folder, then deleting it and that works. So at least i can delete the files. I'm suspecting that somehow the while loop runs "too fast", finding the files again that the haven't yet deleted or something like that. Guessing here.

Comment: That might be it. If i wait (i used 4 seconds) then list the files in the folder, then delete them (without any while loop) the files are correctly listed and then deleted. If i remove the 4s delay, it only deletes some of the files and returns errors on others.

Comment: Sorry for spamming now, but i think i found a solution using timers. I'll post if it works

Comment: @Attaque as you said, you are probably "too fast". The file could well still be in use by other applications after you receive the change notification. Note that this can affect both the *processing* and the *deletion* of the file (depending on how other applications use the file). You will have to use a timer to defer those actions if you want to allow other files to be processed while you wait.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I figured it out last night. I have to finish a first poc for this project, but I'll update this post as soon as i have the time to get it described correctly. Thank you all!

Comment: "I'll update this post as soon as i have the time to get it described correctly" Please don't update the question with a solution. Post your solution as an *answer* - it's fine to answer your own questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be two problems. One of the problems was that the system was too fast, hereby reading and deleting the files at the same time as the system. I resolved this problem by adding a QTimer which was reset each time a signal from the monitored folder was fired. 500ms from the last change of the system was sufficient. Instead of continuesly reading the files in this folder with QFileSystemWatcher and adding them to a queue, as i originally did, I created a function to mute the system watcher while processing the files in the folder. To compensate the function of the file watcher, i created a recursive loop in the processing thread so that it would keep reading the specified files for as long as there still were files. This could be done in one thread though. You all talk code, so here goes:

**Signal and slot setup**

```
// Setting up folder monitoring.
watcher.addPath(worker->monitoredPath);
QObject::connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(directoryChanged(QString)), this,
SLOT(updateQueue()));
// Timer
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(startProcess()));
connect(this, SIGNAL(processRequest()), thread, SLOT(start()));
...

void MainWindow::updateQueue() {
  // Starts or restarts the call to start process. Prevents multiple signals from
  // many files added at once
  timer->start(500);
}
...
void MainWindow::startProcess() {

  if(!thread->isRunning()) {
    emit processRequest();
    muteWatcher(true);  // From here on a recursive loop in dataprocessor checks
                        // the folder for new files.
  }
  timer->stop();

}
```

**Mute file watcher**

```
void MainWindow::muteWatcher(bool toggle) {
  if(toggle) {
    watcher.removePath(worker->monitoredPath);
  } else {
    watcher.addPath(worker->monitoredPath);
  }
}
```

**Processing thread**

```
void DataProcessor::initialize() {
  QDir dir(this->monitoredPath);
  dir.setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files);
  dir.setSorting(QDir::Time);

  QList<QString> dFiles;

  foreach(QFileInfo file, dir.entryInfoList()) {

    if(file.suffix().toLower() == "txt") {
        dFiles.append(file.fileName());
    }
  }

  if(dFiles.count() == 0) { // Base case
    emit muteWatcher(false); // Start monitoring the folder again
    emit finished(); // end the thread
    return true;
  }

  // PROCESSING HERE

  initializeLabel();

}
```

The next thing was to go to go to the preferences of the printer i was printing to, in order to prevent this printer from adding spool files to the folder. You can enable this by clicking "print directly to printer". This solved most of my problems and i was able to delete a web of delays that i had created in order to prevet the program from reading the files produced by the printer.

Hope this helps someone!